# Wordpress make Ajax call to my theme

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

This is my situation: I have a slide, like the image below,  that needs to be responsive. This slide was created from scratch and its working fine, however it's not responsive.

[image]

In order to be responsive I need to know the width of the screen of the user so instead of showing 4 slides, I show 3, 2 and 1 (if its a phone).

With that said, I need my slider to be loaded through ajax and I will pass through params the user screen width.

My theme folder is structured this way:

```
wp-contents/themes/my-theme
...functions.php
...header.php
...footer.php
...index.php
...single.php
```

I need to make a Ajax call to `functions.php` to a function that I have created. So I added the following:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_posts_list', 'my_ajax_posts_list_handler');

function my_ajax_posts_list_handler() 
{
    echo 'hello, width: ' . $_POST['width'];
    wp_die();
}
```

In the `footer.php` file I added some testing javascript code:

```
$(function()
{
    var width   = $(window).width();
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'; // Dunno what is this..

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: 
        {
            action: 'wp_ajax_posts_list',
            width: width
        },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

**My problems**:

1. The URL being executed is this `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_posts_list`
2. The URL response code is 400
3. The URL responde value is '0'

Comment: Could you try with those changes, action : 'posts_list' and url: ajax_object.ajax_url. Good information here : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action is actually called `post_list`. `wp_ajax_` is just a prefix. You also should add the same action with prefix `wp_ajax_nopriv_` otherwise it wil not work when you are logged out. I also see you do `type: 'GET'` in your javascript but use `$_POST` in your PHP. Do one of the two.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_posts_list', 'my_ajax_posts_list_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_posts_list', 'my_ajax_posts_list_handler');

function my_ajax_posts_list_handler()
{
    echo 'hello, width: ' . $_POST['width'];
    wp_die();
}
```

Here the JS:

```
<script>
    $( function () {
        var width = $( window ).width();

        // var ajaxurl = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';

        $.ajax( {
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'posts_list',
                width: width
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function ( response ) {
                console.log( response );
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```